# RecordType query with Soap API returns 0 results

Tags: soap-api, soap, record-type

Im currently trying to execute this query using a SOAP API connection:

```
"SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'Account' AND DeveloperName = 'Salon' ORDER BY Name"
```

Edit: Ive also tried `"SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM RecordType"` and still I get a 0 objects response as well.

I need to use the Partner WSDL since some of the other queries use custom objects and such, but this line of code works perfectly under enterprise.

Is there any sort of limitation to what partner can fetch?
There output itself does not contain any errors, the result is just empty.

Thanks!

The output:

```
QueryResult Object
(
[queryLocator] => 
[done] => 1
[records] => Array
    (
    )

[size] => 0
[pointer] => 0
[sf:QueryResult:private] => SforcePartnerClient Object
    (
        [sforce:protected] => SforceSoapClient Object
            (
                [trace] => 1
                [compression] => 32
                [_encoding] => utf-8
                [_features] => 1
                [_user_agent] => salesforce-toolkit-php/27.0
                [_soap_version] => 1
                [sdl] => Resource id #39
                [location] => https://na24.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/34.0/00D1a000000aaOO
                [__default_headers] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => SoapHeader Object
                            (
                                [namespace] => urn:partner.soap.sforce.com
                                [name] => SessionHeader
                                [data] => Array
                                    (
                                        [sessionId] => xxx
                                    )

                                [mustUnderstand] => 
                            )

                    )
```

Update:
I've went and created two instances of the connection, one for enterprise one for partner. I know this isn't ideal but there seems to be something wrong with the web service for certain queues when using personal.
Any additional input will be much appreciated

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried using a describe call instead?

Comment: Hi! I just tried it out and everything seems in order, I get a full response with the whole description of the object and its params. If needed I can paste the whole thing.. I've triple checked the WSDL and that didn't help either, FYI.

Comment: Is it possible there is something in the response that is confusing the PHP toolkit. Can you try the SOQL queries that aren't returning any rows in another tool. The developer console, workbench, or Soap UI would both be good candidates.

Comment: Hi Daniel, the queries work perfectly in the developer console. I don't think it has to do with the PHP toolkit, because other queries running through the same instance are working perfectly, its just this one object that is giving me a headache

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the RecordTypes in the Org are not Active or not assigned to the partner's Profile thus not searchable

Comment: Do you happen to know how to assign them? 
The odd thing is that I just created 2 objects, and im using the enterprise edition for this single query.. but another query down the line that selects from RecordTypes DID RETURN an object, but ... it had an ARRAY of 2 ids..! When performing this same query with the enterprise edition, i got the output correct